# Puzzle with character order

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, group-theory, generating-functions, combinations

Suppose I have **3 letters** a, b, c and I want to find the minimum length of a string that uses all the **double combinations** of the aforementioned letters.

How should I do it or how are such problems called in order to search for them online?

**Example:**

The 3 letters `a, b, c` produce 9 double combinations:

1. aa
2. bb
3. cc
4. ab
5. ac
6. bc
7. ba
8. ca
9. cb

What I want is a string that in its length will include all the combinations **only one time** or a **minimum number of times**, which in this case is only one time. For example the `aabbcc` includes the combinations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 like this:

- 1: **aa** bbcc
- 2: aa **bb** cc
- 3: aabb **cc**
- 4: a **ab** bcc
- 6: aab **bc** c

The string that I want is actually this:
`aabbccacba` which includes all the double combinations only once:

- 1: **aa** bbccacba
- 2: aa **bb** ccacba
- 3: aabb **cc** acba
- 4: a **ab** bccacba
- 6: aab **bc** cacba
- 8: aabbc **ca** cba
- 5: aabbcc **ac** ba
- 7: aabbccac **ba**
- 9: aabbcca **cb** a

I am not concerned about the order that the combinations appear, so any similar string that includes the 9 combinations a minimum number of times would suffice. I only need that the double combinations to appear the minimum number of times.

The above concerns 3 letters and double combinations; let's call it a *3:2 problem*. Imagine now that I want to have the flexibility to produce this string for *4:3, 7:2, 9:6 problems*, etc...

Sincere apologies if this is not a question on mathematics.

Comment: This is not precisely what you want, but take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence

Comment: Hi, you should look up "De Bruijn Sequence"

Comment: @Phicar, great minds.... ;)

Comment: indeed @BarryCipra . ;)

Comment: Can't believe you guys, you replied the same minute! Thank you! Also can't believe a so innocent question of mine could frame me for brute-force attacks. :D

Comment: @BarryCipra Well, this is what I wanted and wikipedia has already the python code ready! There is also a nice card trick based on de Brujin sequences: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWG6e-yBL94 The only modification I need is to just  add the first letters of the sequence (depending on the requested length) at the end of the series.